# Outlook messing up HTML link - not maintaining % character

Tags: html, outlook, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to create a link in an html email and the target contains '%0D'

This is the link I want to reach:

```
https://bitbucket.org/blah/blue/branches/compare/0.6.0%0D0.5.0#diff
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
<a href=https://bitbucket.org/blah/blue/branches/compare/0.6.0%0D0.5.0#diff>Show diffs</a>
```

The link code works fine if I just save a .html file and open that in a browser.

If I send it in an email and view that it the outlook web interface, when I move the mouse over, the overlay which says the original link (it says "original url - click or tap if you trust this link") - in there it seems to be correct.

At the bottom of the browser though, where it's showing the actual link, it's all long and garbled and has some stuff about nam11.safelinks.protection.outlook. When I click the link, it opens a page with the %0D removed.

This the page which gets opened (which is invalid):

```
https://bitbucket.org/blah/blue/branches/compare/0.6.00.5.0#diff
```

I did some research and tried replacing the % with %25 but then all the characters stayed in there, which broke the url. Is there any way I can send that html so that outlook doesn't break the link?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to pass the `%0D` *verbatim*, don't you?

I suggest you try encoding just the `%` char (which yields `%25`) and thus the URL would be as follows:

```
https://bitbucket.org/blah/blue/branches/compare/0.6.0%250D0.5.0#diff
```

Comment: hmm yes as I mentioned I tried that - the link that came out of that was unchanged (ie. the %25 remained in the link), so also broken

Comment: Ok, I get it (didn't read the last part of your message). Please note that invisible chars, especially the `%0D` carriage-return is dangerous and may be used in potentially threatening URLs.

Comment: i see - it's kind of annoying bitbucket uses them in their urls